# C++ Terminal Not Working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a C++ program. This program not working. I changed `"externalConsole": false` to `"externalConsole": true`, it works and it gives me console. But I want to run with `"externalConsole": false`. Is there a way to do this? Relevant outputs is below.

Program (asd.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x  = 1525, z;
    cout << "x number is " << x << endl;
    cin >> z;
    cout << "z number 2 is " << z << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/asd.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Terminal

```
Windows PowerShell

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\hakan\projects\onecpp>  & 'c:\Users\hakan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.3.0-insiders4\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-emhvpzpo.syb' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-dht4nkur.p5d' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-cpkcr2pw.mzq' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-v2fsb4cd.no1' '--dbgExe=C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi' 
PS C:\Users\hakan\projects\onecpp>
```

Debug Console

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
=cmd-param-changed,param="args",value="2>CON 1>CON <CON"
[New Thread 9284.0x16f4]
x number is 1525
z number 2 is 1013
The program 'C:\Users\hakan\projects\onecpp\asd.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

I make a program to enter data, I cannot enter data and it writes 1013.

Build is working: `Build finished successfully.`

Comment: Looks like it's working correctly from the debug console output?

Comment: Yes, but when I make a program to enter data, I cannot enter data, the program closes directly.

Comment: I think if you want to use the standard input then you need to use an external console

Comment: Apparently that's what needs to be done in vscode.

Answer (score 2):

The setting `"externalConsole": false` is deprecated. Try using `"console": "integratedTerminal"` with the latest version of Visual Studio Code instead. For me console input in the integrated terminal works then.

Comment: Nothing has changed. `Property console is not allowed.` gave a warning.

Comment: @en0ndev Seems like the difference is you using cppdbg. With that and MinGW i have the same issue. Since your output is asd.exe i am assuming you are using Windows. Try using "type": "cppvsdbg" with "console": "integratedTerminal". This should work.

Comment: It looks like it will work, but I not getting any output. https://imgur.com/saSgIn2

Comment: @en0ndev Youre are looking at the "Debug Console" tab. That's the wrong one, your application console input/output goes to "Terminal". I have to admit this is very misleading.

Comment: There is no change in debugging in the terminal. https://imgur.com/gjgaLWH